# nested Bash for loop not iterating correctly?

Tags: bash, curl, jq

I am using a curl command to get json data from an application

the example curl response

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 344,
            "name": "ip-172-20-94-68",
            "status": "offline",
       
        },
        {
            "id": 345,
            "name": "ip-172-20-95-119",
            "status": "offline",
        }
    ]
}
```

My bash script

```
 ipAddresses=$(curl -s -X GET "$hostUrl" -u :"$EncodedPAT" | jq -r ".value[] | select(.status==\"offline\").name")
 ids=$(curl -s -X GET "$hostUrl" -u :"$EncodedPAT" | jq -r ".value[] | select(.status==\"offline\").id")

        for ipAddress in "${ipAddresses[@]}"
            do
                for id in "${ids[@]}"
                    do
                    echo "ipAddress: ${ipAddress} id: ${id}"
                done
        done
```

output

```
ipAddress: ip-172-20-94-68
ip-172-20-95-119
ip-172-20-95-113
ip-172-20-94-96
ip-172-20-94-86
id: 344
345
346
348
350
```

So it looks like it is only iterating through the outermost loop once, and not iterating through the inner loops (just uses first element).

expected output

```
ipAddress: ip-172-20-94-68 id: 344
ipAddress: ip-172-20-95-119 id: 345
ipAddress: ip-172-20-95-113 id: 346
ipAddress: ip-172-20-94-96 id: 348
ipAddress: ip-172-20-94-86 id: 350
```

I've looked elsewhere on the net but am having trouble finding anything relevant.

Any guesses as to what might be wrong?

Comment: A nested loop does exactly what you're seeing. You don't want that. Just loop once, by _index_.

Comment: Or -- here's a thought -- why not have just _one_ `jq` call give you pairs as its output? You'd also stop calling `curl` twice that way, and thus create less load on the server.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks i have not thought of that im kinda new to jq

Comment: `while IFS=$'\t' read -r name id; do echo "IP address: $name; id: $id"; done < <(curl -s -X GET "$hostUrl" -u :"$EncodedPAT" | jq -r '.value[] | select(.status=="offline") | [.name, .id] | @tsv')`

Comment: (of course, if the only thing you're trying to do is generate the strings as output, that can be done just in jq alone with no shell loop at all: `curl -s -X GET "$hostUrl" -u :"$EncodedPAT" | jq -r '.value[] | select(.status=="offline") | "ipAddress: \(.name) id: \(.id)"'`

Comment: Since your `echo` is, according to the output you give here, executed exactly once, it means that the outer loop is executed once and during this execution the inner loop is also executed once. One obvious problem is that you access i.e. `ipAddresses` as if it were an **array**, but you define it as **scalar** (holding a single string). Perhaps you should also initialize it as array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine this into a single [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) call:

```
.value[] | select(.status == "offline") | "ipAddress: \(.name) id: \(.id)"
```

Gives:

```
"ipAddress: ip-172-20-94-68 id: 344"
"ipAddress: ip-172-20-95-119 id: 345"
```

---

##### [Online JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/j3xaiGVQuR5)